# How to enable local LAN access when using Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client via command line?

Tags: networking, vpn, cisco-vpn-client, cisco-anyconnect

When you run the Cisco AnyConnect Secure Mobility Client GUI, you can go to settings preferences and check allow local lan. This works for me. However, I do not want to use the GUI because reasons. I have been using the vpncli.exe in the app folder. It works fine except I cannot get local lan access when I connect this way. How do I rectify the situation?